# Adding basic custom HTML

Tags: iframe, spo

I am trying to add a weather forecast to my sharepoint homepage and but it will not work. I am using sharepoint online and a modern page. I am trying to add the code below with the "Embed" app.

```
<iframe id="forecast_embed" type="text/html" frameborder="0" height="245" width="100%" src="https://forecast.io/embed/#lat=38.738123&lon=-104.883909&name=C5 in Charlotte, NC”></iframe>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error while adding this code?

Answer (score 0):

Could be as simple as a bad quote symbol...

```
, NC”

, NC"
```

You will need to add forecast.io to "HTML Field Security" list.

Answer (score 0):

There are two tings you need to do:

1. Make sure the HTML for the iframe is valid.

Instead of this:

```
<iframe id="forecast_embed" type="text/html" frameborder="0" height="245" width="100%" src="https://forecast.io/embed/#lat=38.738123&lon=-104.883909&name=C5 in Charlotte, NC”></iframe>
```

you need this:

```
<iframe id="forecast_embed" type="text/html" frameborder="0" height="245" width="100%" src="https://forecast.io/embed/#lat=38.738123&lon=-104.883909&name=C5 in Charlotte, NC"></iframe>
```

Note that ” is replaced with "

2. You need to allow forecast.io do[main to be used in iFrames in your Site settings](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/allow-or-restrict-the-ability-to-embed-content-on-sharepoint-pages-e7baf83f-09d0-4bd1-9058-4aa483ee137b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

[image]

[image]

If this does not work and the Embeded webpart still complais about the domain - use "Allow contributors to insert iframes from any domain" option:

[image]

After you are done it should work just fine:

[image]